# JQuery => update multiple selects depending one

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using this JS code to update one select (regions) depending one other (country). This code is perfect and works properly. I ask my app an array of regions and have the response in JSON.

My JS code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    url: '/webapp/update_regions/' + id,
    timeout: 2000,
    beforeSend : function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json") },
        success: function(data) {                                        
          // fill regions
          $.each(data, function(i,j) {
            row = "<option value=\"" + j.region.id + "\">" + j.region.name + "</option>";   
            $(row).appendTo("select#region_id");                     
          }); 
        }
      });
</script>
```

I want to update another select depending the first (country), so I need to update 2 selects in the same time. Does I need to do 2 ajax requests (and getting 2 json array) or can I get one JSON response (1 hash with 2 arrays) and manage id correctly in the JS code above ?

My question: how to handle the response data if I get this hash of 2 arrays with this code (so data is a hash, not an array):

```
// fill regions
              $.each(data, function(i,j) {
                row = "<option value=\"" + j.region.id + "\">" + j.region.name + "</option>";   
                $(row).appendTo("select#region_id");                     
              });

// fill appellations
$.each(data, function(i,j) {
                    row = "<option value=\"" + j.appellation.id + "\">" + j.appellation.name + "</option>";   
                    $(row).appendTo("select#appellation_id");                     
                  });
```

In fact, I don't know how to divide the JSON hash... to get data['regions'] and data['appellations']... for example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK? the solution is really simple with a hash, just add ["region"] to **data**:

```
      $.each(data["regions"], function(i,j) {
        row = "<option value=\"" + j.region.id + "\">" + j.region.name + "</option>";   
        $(row).appendTo("select#wine_region_id");                     
      });
```